# Setting correct autofill username and password

Tags: javascript, angular, html, browser, autofill

In my angular application I have a registration form which has the following fields in the same order

1) email id

2) otp

when the otp is entered the below fields becomes visible

3) full name

4) password

[image]

The last element is the submit button.

When we click on submit button the browser prompts the user to save the username and password.

I want the Autofill to save email as the username but its taking the fullname as the username. I tried adding a hidden field with Email filled but it worked on Firefox and dint work on Chrome

Is there any other way to achieve this by not editing the order of the form elements?

Adding html for the inputs

```
<input type="email" [(ngModel)]="email" name="userName" required />
 <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="fullName" name="fullName" id="fullName" #fullName="ngModel" dirname="fullName"  />
<input [(ngModel)]="password" id="pwd" type="password" name="password" #password="ngModel"  required />
```

Please guide

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, the browser uses the "name" attribute to determine what is what for the input field. i think you can simply change the name from "email" to "username" and it should work

Comment: @Bolphgolph name is username only for email field